# What can't I install ncurses-dev in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: software-installation

When I run the command:

```
apt-get install kernel-package ncurses-dev bzip2
```

I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libncurses5-dev' instead of 'ncurses-dev'
bzip2 is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kernel-package : Depends: build-essential but it is not going to be installed
 libncurses5-dev : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 5.9-10) but 5.9-10ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libncurses5 (= 5.9-10) but 5.9-10ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libtinfo-dev (= 5.9-10) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: ncurses-bin (= 5.9-10) but 5.9-10ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: try sudo apt-get install -f ?

Comment: @Hamza Are you still looking for a solution to this?

Comment: You have unmet dependencies. Pruge remove the dependencies that are being showed. Then try again.

Comment: As this question is too old and related with EOL Ubuntu release, I'm voting this to close as Of-topic